# Does java have a builtin class that can be used to implement a hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable

java version "1.8.0_92"

I have seen `java.util.HashTable<K,V>`

Just wondering is that the same as a normal hashtable that handles collisions and computes a hash function?

I have seen a lot of people implement the hashtable themselves and just wondering about this.

Thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: Note that Hashtable shouldn't be used anymore. Use HashMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a nice documentation about those classes:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashtable_class.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_hashtable.htm

As it describes it as:

> Hashtable was part of the original java.util and is a concrete implementation of a Dictionary.
>
> However, Java 2 re-engineered Hashtable so that it also implements the Map interface. Thus, Hashtable is now integrated into the collections framework. It is similar to HashMap, but is synchronized.